# How can I disable writing BeanShell log row in JMeter report (summary.csv file)?

Tags: csv, logging, jmeter, beanshell

I have some JMeter script with BeanShell Sampler:

[image: BeanShell Sampler]

After run we can see BeanShell Sampler log in 'summary.csv':

[image: BeanShell Sampler log]

How can I disable writing of BeanShell Sampler log into 'summary.csv'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add at end of sampler:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore();
```

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--

Note that for performance reasons, it is much better to use JSR223 Sampler and Groovy instead of Beanshell Sampler, see:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.